# Ajax calls in angular4? which is better $ajax or $http

Tags: jquery, ajax, angular

Insted of $http to get data i am using $.ajax({}) same like in javascript. is it good way to use $.ajax({}); calls in angular4?
which one is good method for this?
    right now i am using this method for ajax calls in angular4

```
  $.ajax({
  url:'api',
  type:'POST',
  data:dataString,
  success:function(data)
  {},error(xhr,status,error)
  {}
  });
```

Comment: you are confusing the libraries with the language, jquery $.ajax, $http all do the same, they have different implementation but on the backend the server side language doesn't see that you use $.ajax or $http, if you are using angular stick with angular syntax

Comment: I seriously cant understand why ppl keep trying to mix angular with jquery when is not even necessary

Answer (score 0):

you should follow the architecture of angular io using '@angular/http'.
Mixing both programming styles (Angular + jQuery) will also be confusing and sub-optimal. But nothing prevents you to reach your goal in whatever way you like!

Comment: where did you saw that angular io use jquery?

Comment: my bad, I mean angular js.